# How can we delete files inside certain directory flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to delete files from any folders of android device using flutter programatically. Is there any way to delete files created as in the code. I downloaded files using dio. and want to delete the files downloaded like this.
`var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();     await dio.download(fileURL, "${dir.path}/books/$fileName.pdf",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete the file after a button pressed, this is what I suggest:

```
onPressed: () async {
  Directory dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final targetFile = Directory("${dir.path}/books/$fileName.pdf");
  if(targetFile.existsSync()) {
    targetFile.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  }
}
```

Comment: If this answer help you with your problem, you should mark it as the right answer. Cheers @Krishadk